# How come changing an array in a function affects the original array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Why the changes I applied to the `a[]` in `selection_sort` function will also applied to `series[]` in the `main` function? Can anyone explains this to me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMS 8

void selection_sort(int a[], int n);

int main(void)
{

    int i, series[NUMS];

    printf("\nEnter %d numbers: ", NUMS);
    for (i = 0; i < NUMS; i++)
        scanf("%d", &series[i]);

    selection_sort(series, NUMS);

    printf("Sorted: ");
    for (i = 0; i < NUMS; i++)
        printf("%d ", series[i]);
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}

void selection_sort(int a[], int n)
{

    if (n == 0) return;

    int i, li = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (a[i] > a[li])
            li = i;

    i = a[n-1];
    a[n-1] = a[li];
    a[li] = i;
    selection_sort(a, n - 1);
}
```

I expect that changes in `a[]` array can't interfere the elements inside `series[]`. But this confuse me.

Comment: `a` is not an array.

Comment: The parameter `a` will resolve to a pointer when compiled. So when you pass `series` to `selection_sort` you are actually passing the address of where `series` is in memory.

Comment: @dedecos May I know why this only happen to array only?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html

Comment: When calling the function using the array name, you are actually giving the address of first element in the array. So instead of making copy of your array, compiler will pass the address of original array `series[]`. So any edit will go to the value pointed by the address, i.e. the original array.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yes, I saw that and I ment that. From the title we already assumed that some kind of misunderstanding of array assignment exists. And so it is.

Comment: @thebusybee that title was the perfect example of a bad title. No context and not a single indication about what the problem is about. Also using random variable names, which basically creates a question that will never be hit in search results, making it almost useless.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying

Answer (score 2):

Your elements are being manipulated because when you pass an array to a function, that array is treated as a pointer pointing to the base location of the array, hence manipulating your elements

Comment: Reference: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)